# Difference between "blame" and "allegation"?

Tags: word-difference

blame - feel or declare that (someone or something) is responsible for a fault or wrong.

allegation - a claim or assertion that someone has done something illegal or wrong, typically one made without proof.

I don't understand what's the difference between these words. Aren't they synonyms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question! They are not synonyms. I will try to explain the differences the best I can.

The first difference is that "Allegation" is a noun, and "Blame" is *usually* a verb. Blame can also a noun, but I think it is more common to use it as a verb. "Allegation" means "*A* claim that someone is guilty" (noun) and "Blame" means "*to* claim that someone is guilty" (verb). So the differences between your two definitions come down to the difference between claim as a verb and claim as a noun. [Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=define+allegation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#channel=fs&q=define+claim) gives the verb definition as

> State or assert that something is the case, typically without providing evidence or proof.

and also gives the noun definition as:

> An assertion of the truth of something, typically one that is disputed or in doubt.

So if I were to *Claim* (verb) that I just won the lottery, I *stated or asserted* that I won the lottery. I also made a *claim* (noun) that I just won the lottery. I made an assertion of the fact that I won the lottery.

Now as for "blame" as a noun, the differences are more obvious. "Blame" as a noun is synonymous with "guilt". If someone makes allegations that I am guilty, it is still a possibility that I am innocent. That only means that someone *says* that I am guilty. The same is true if someone *blames* (verb) me. However, if "The blame is on me" or "I take the blame" (both nouns) then it does not leave an option that I am innocent. It means that I *am* guilty.

Answer (score 2):

They are quite different both syntactically and semantically.

- *Blame* as a verb assigns responsibility to an agent for a deplorable fact or act. There are two constructions:

  1) with the agent as direct object and the fact or act as object of the  preposition *for*

  > He blames her for his brother's death.
  >   He blames her for betraying his brother.

  2) with the fact or act as direct object and the agent as object of the preposition *on*

  > He blames his brother's death on her.
  >   He blames his brother's betrayal on her.

  The noun *blame* usually designates responsibility for the act.

  > He assigns the blame for his brother's death to her.
  >   She is at blame for his brother's death.
- The verb *allege* merely asserts a fact. It is frequently used in contexts where the fact is some criminal or improper action; but it is not confined to that context. In fact, it is most often encountered in news stories where it serves as a 'hedge' to emphasize the reporter's neutrality with respect to the assertion. *Allege* usually takes a *that* clause as its object, but it may also take a noun phrase:

  > The police complaint alleges that he robbed the convenience store.
  >   Sen. Hill alleges that the Commerce Department is too friendly with industry.
  >   Prof. Sartorius alleges that the name 'Moses' should be understood as Egyptian *msy*, 'he is born'.
  >   Prof. Sartorius an Egyptian origin for the name Moses.

  The noun *allegation* designates either an act of alleging or the fact alleged. It may take a *that* clause or *of* + noun phrase as its complement.

  > The police have made serious allegations against him.
  >   Sen. Hill has made the news again, with allegations of Commerce Department improprieties.
  >   Prof. Sartorius' allegation that the name 'Moses' should be understood as Egyptian *msy*, 'he is born' is not widely endorsed.